# Convention for Hiding API Key

Tags: git, github, api-key

I have a project (Swift but this applies to any project pretty much) and I end up using an API Key to make a call to OpenWeatherMap. I wanted to publish my repository without revealing my key. What's the best way to go about this so that I am able to both: hide my private API key (and instruct users to obtain their own in order to make the application work), and continue to work on the project using my own API key as seamlessly as possible.

Comment: It almost does, the linked question doesn't say what to do if I already have a project that I have made commits to that contains my API key in the history

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+file

Comment: Yeah I think I'll just start with a new repo